# Border Padding for a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4

I created a standard border around my UIView like so:

```
 vwGroup.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
 vwGroup.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
```

but I would like to have 5px of padding/margin/spacing between the UIView, and the border that surrounds it.

Right now it just draws the border immediately around it. I'd like to push it out so there is clear space between.

Any suggestions? I suspect insets are the way to go but can't figure it out.

Thank you!

Comment: How about try wrap your view in another clear color view and add border into that view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insets isn't the way to go. You use inset for padding a view's internal content from its margins. For what you need your best option is to wrap your `vwGroup` inside another `UIView` and set the border in the wrapping view. Something like:

```
let wrappingView = UIView(frame: someFrame)
wrappingView.backgroundColor = .clear
wrappingView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
wrappingView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
wrappingView.addSubview(vwGroup)
```

Of course this is just for you to get the big picture. You might want to set proper frames/constraints.

Answer (score 1):

***swift 5.4***

call like this:

```
customView.layer.innerBorder()
```

did it, by add a sublayer

```
extension CALayer {


    func innerBorder(borderOffset: CGFloat = 24.0, borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue, borderWidth: CGFloat = 2) {
        let innerBorder = CALayer()
        innerBorder.frame = CGRect(x: borderOffset, y: borderOffset, width: frame.size.width - 2 * borderOffset, height: frame.size.height - 2 * borderOffset)
        innerBorder.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        innerBorder.borderWidth = borderWidth
        innerBorder.name = "innerBorder"
        insertSublayer(innerBorder, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, it is helpful for you.**

***First, Add this extension***

```
extension CALayer {
    func addGradientBorder(colors:[UIColor],width:CGFloat = 1) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1.0,y:1.0)
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map({$0.cgColor})

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = width
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer

        self.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

***Then add the UIView with border***

```
let vwGroup = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 150, width: 200, height: 200))
vwGroup.backgroundColor = .red

//-- This is for padding between boarder and view -- you can set padding color ---
vwGroup.layer.addGradientBorder(colors:[UIColor.black,UIColor.black] , width: 40)

//--  This is for outer boarder -- you can also change the color of outer boarder --
vwGroup.layer.addGradientBorder(colors:[UIColor.white,UIColor.white] , width: 10)
self.view.addSubview(vwGroup)
```

**Output is:**

[image]

Comment: so if I already have a view called vwGroup, where does that go in your code? I am trying to just call it like this: vwGroup(colors:[UIColor.white,UIColor.white] , width: 10) and it's surrounding it, but it's putting it as a gradient border (and no spacing).

Comment: `addGradientBorder` call this method twice with vwGroup, because of first for padding and the second for `border` of UIView. and don't forget to remove default border width and border color from vwGroup